# Loading Arbitrary Object with Load() In Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm a newbie in Hibernate and would like to abstract the load() method of hibernate session so that i can use it to load any arbitrary object from a database. I'm creating a utility class to persist and find objects in a database because am working with multiple classes.

Since the the load() method accepts a class name followed by the class keyword i am struggling how to do it. i did the following but is giving me errors ::

```
Object ob = session.load(Object.class, id);
```

How do i get it right?

thanks

Comment: This is not the correct way and you should not use Object. Use your class name.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Is there a way to pass the class name dynamically?

Comment: `Class c = Class.forName("your.fully.qualified.name.of.class");
`

Comment: And I smell a design flaw here.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do a request without specifying of a class name because of Hibernate need a mapping information from a class to make SQL requests.

You can use HQL. Something like this (maybe, you can use a query parameter for id to better caching)

```
public static <T> getById(String persistentClassName, Long id) { 
  return (T) session.createQuery(String.format("from %s where id=%d",
      persistentClassName, id).uniqueResult();
}

Persitent p = getById("Persistent", 100L);
```

But as @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ suggested it is not a very good design. if you want to have ideas for more convenient approach to design such utilities methods you can take a look at [fluent-hibernate](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate). With it you can do such kind of requests

`List<Transaction> transactions = H.<Transaction> request(Transaction.class)
    .innerJoin("customer").innerJoin("merchant").proj("customer.name")
    .proj("merchant.name").proj("amountDue").transform(Transaction.class).list();`